# Do all tumors form the same way?

Tags: genetics, cancer, human-genetics, pathogenesis

Do all tumors - both benign and malignant - form when proto-oncogenes and/or tumor suppressor genes experience mutations? Were all malignant tumors once benign?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malignant_transformation).